Comedy where man loses poker hands to a child
There was a guy who was watching someone's kid and when the Dad gets back, they are playing cards at the table. 
The kid proclaims, "I win!" and he has a handful of worthless cards (playing poker) but the adult isn't able to explain the game so he let's the kid take all of the chips. THe kid says twice, "I win... " and then, "Because I win!" 
Does anyone recognize the premise of this scene?

The movie you are thinking of is Big Daddy. Adam Sandler plays a layabout that ends up taking care of his roommates illegitimate child. The scene that you recall was during a poker game with some of his friends:



The link to the Wiki synopsis of the film is here.
